# webcam not working anymore

Tags: skype, webcam, driver

I was using Skype, and suddenly the internal iSight camera stopped working. It's not the first time this has happened. I already fixed this problem with a reboot, but I would like to find a solution without a reboot. Is there a way to push the driver back, or do some more accurate diagnostic?

I have MacOSX 10.6.7 on a macbook 13" unibody.

Comment: "the camera stopped working". What camera is that? The internal iSight or an external Canon camera?

Comment: @marconcini: the internal camera. Disregard my bug report. I then realized it was due to my photo camera, and has nothing to do with the internal iSight (Initially I thought it was just because Canon made the iSight, so it registered as such to the USB driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the camera is taken over, somehow, by the google talk browser plugin. I solved by doing the following. From a terminal, I issued the following command

```
ps uaxw |grep Firefox
```

It will show a list of the processes under Firefox. One of them may be something like

```
sbo      21173   0.0  0.1   414040   2492   ??  S     5May11   0:07.47 
   /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/plugin-container.app/Contents/
   MacOS/plugin-container /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/googletalkbrowserplugin.plugin
   -omnijar /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/omni.jar 21168 
   gecko-crash-server-pipe.21168 org.mozilla.machname.855559451 plugin
```

I wrapped the long line. I then proceeded to kill this process (the pid is the first number)

```
  kill 21173
```

and the iSight started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message includes "Canon Digital Camera" I assume that your MBP is connected to an external camera. You can try to eject the device (unplug it from the USB port) and replugin to see whether it helps.

Comment: I am referring to the internal camera. Disregard my bug report. I then realized it was due to my photo camera, and has nothing to do with the internal iSight (Initially I thought it was just because Canon made the iSight, so it registered as such to the USB driver). The internal iSight is not working anymore, and I would like to understand why and how to recover.